# Is there a minimum rep needed to become an Arqade moderator?

Tags: support, election, moderators

Question says it all.  Is there a minimum rep needed or minimum gold badge needed to become an Arqade Moderator?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/1 - Nomination. Up to thirty candidates nominate themselves for the position. You need 300 reputation to nominate yourself.

Answer (score 8):

All elections require a minimum of 300 reputation in order to nominate yourself when the election period is in session. Except for Stack Overflow, which is an order of magnitude higher. But we're not Stack Overflow, so it is 300 here.